# Computing lagged time differences within groups

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery

I have a table with ids, dates, and times of events as shown below

```
ids: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 
dates: 2021.03.10 2021.03.10 2021.03.10 2021.03.11 2021.03.11 2021.03.10 2021.03.11 2021.03.11 2021.03.11 2021.03.11
times: 12:00 12:01 12:03 12:04 12:05 13:01 13:05 13:06 13:12 13:15

t:([] ids:ids; dates:dates; times:times)

ids dates      times
--------------------
1   2021.03.10 12:00
1   2021.03.10 12:01
1   2021.03.10 12:03
1   2021.03.11 12:04
1   2021.03.11 12:05
2   2021.03.10 13:01
2   2021.03.11 13:05
2   2021.03.11 13:06
2   2021.03.11 13:12
2   2021.03.11 13:15
```

I would like to compute the difference between consecutive times within the same date for all ids.   If there is only one time in a single date, I would like the value to be 0.  The desired output would look like

```
ids dates      times   deltaMinutes
----------------------------------
1   2021.03.10 12:00   0
1   2021.03.10 12:01   1
1   2021.03.10 12:03   2
1   2021.03.11 12:04   0
1   2021.03.11 12:05   1
2   2021.03.10 13:01   0
2   2021.03.11 13:05   0
2   2021.03.11 13:06   1
2   2021.03.11 13:12   6
2   2021.03.11 13:15   3
```

Is this achievable with qsql?

Answer (score 2):

```
q)update deltaMinutes:`int$-':[first times;times]by ids,dates from t
ids dates      times deltaMinutes
---------------------------------
1   2021.03.10 12:00 0
1   2021.03.10 12:01 1
1   2021.03.10 12:03 2
1   2021.03.11 12:04 0
1   2021.03.11 12:05 1
2   2021.03.10 13:01 0
2   2021.03.11 13:05 0
2   2021.03.11 13:06 1
2   2021.03.11 13:12 6
2   2021.03.11 13:15 3
2   2021.03.12 11:00 0
```

`-':` is just `deltas` but it seems [deltas](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/deltas/#first-predecessor) isn't supported for binary application